# How Can I Use The Value Of A Variable In One Class To Another?

Tags: java, class, oop, variables, methods

I've defined a variable `withdraw` in class `Account`. It performs the `withdrawl` function just fine that's defined inside the `Account` class. However, I wish to access the value of `withdraw` variable inside the `interest` function present in the `Sav_acct` class. It's taking the value of `withdraw` as 0. How can I use the value of `withdraw` from the `withdrawl` function inside the  `interest` function so I can perform the right mathematical operation?

```
public class Account {
    String customer_name;
    int account_number;
    String type_account;
    int balance = 2500;
    double deposit;

    public static double withdraw;

    void deposit() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("how much do you want to deposit?");
        int amo = sc.nextInt();
        deposit = balance + amo;

        System.out.println("Your current balance is " + balance);
    }

    void withdrawl() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("how much do you want to withdraw?");
        int amo = sc.nextInt();
        withdraw = balance - amo;
        if (withdraw < 0) {
            System.out.println("Your balance is insufficient");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your current balance is " + withdraw);
        }
    }
}

class Curr_acct extends Account {

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    void penalty() {
        double Service_charge = withdraw - 100;
        double falling = Service_charge;

        System.out.println("You've been charged" + " 100" + " due to low balance");
        System.out.println("Your current amount is " + falling);
    }
}

class Sav_acct extends Account {
    void interest() {
        double interest;
        interest = (1 % 100) * withdraw;
        double total_amount = interest + withdraw;
        System.out.println("Your new balance with interest is " + total_amount);
    }
}

class publish {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String n = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your account type: Savings Account or Current Account");
        String t = sc.nextLine();
        if ("Savings Account".equals(t)) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to deposit or withdraw amount?");
            String d = sc.nextLine();
            if ("deposit".equals(d)) {
                Account de = new Account();
                de.deposit();
            }
            else if ("withdraw".equals(d)) {
                Account wi = new Account();
                wi.withdrawl();
                Sav_acct in = new Sav_acct();
                in.interest();
            }
        }
        else if ("Current Account".equals(t)) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to deposit or withdraw amount?");
            String d = sc.nextLine();
            if ("deposit".equals(d)) {
                Account de = new Account();
                de.deposit();
            }
            else if ("withdraw".equals(d)) {
                Account wi = new Account();
                wi.withdrawl();
                if (withdraw < 2000) {
                    Curr_acct pe = new Curr_acct();
                    pe.penalty();
                }
                else {

                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("please enter the correct account type as per the options provided on the screen");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : Modified the code.But interest is still 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Account {

    String customer_name;
    int account_number;
    String type_account;
    int balance = 2500;
    double deposit;

    double withdraw;

    void deposit() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("how much do you want to deposit?");
        int amo = sc.nextInt();
        deposit = balance + amo;

        System.out.println("Your current balance is " + deposit);
    }

    void withdrawl() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("how much do you want to withdraw?");

        int amo = sc.nextInt();

        withdraw = balance - amo;

    }

}

class Curr_acct extends Account {

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")

    void penalty() {

        if (withdraw < 2000 && withdraw > 0) {
            double Service_charge = withdraw - 100;
            double falling = Service_charge;
            System.out.println("Your balance is " + withdraw);
            System.out.println("You've been charged a service charge" + " 100" + " due to a below the limit balance");
            System.out.println("Your current amount is " + falling);
        } else if (withdraw <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Your balance is insufficient");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your current balance is " + withdraw);
        }

    }

}

class Sav_acct extends Account {

    void interest() {
        if (withdraw < 0) {
            System.out.println("Your balance is insufficient");
        } else {
            double interests;

            interests = (1 / 100) * withdraw;
            double total_amount = interests + withdraw;
            System.out.println("Your new balance with interest is " + total_amount);
        }

    }

}

public class publish {

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name");

        String n = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your account type: Savings Account or Current Account");
        String t = sc.nextLine();

        if ("Savings Account".equals(t)) {
            Sav_acct ac = new Sav_acct();
            System.out.println("Do you want to deposit or withdraw amount?");
            String d = sc.nextLine();
            if ("deposit".equals(d)) {

                ac.deposit();
            } else if ("withdraw".equals(d)) {

                ac.withdrawl();

                ac.interest();

            }
        }

        else if ("Current Account".equals(t)) {
            Curr_acct ac = new Curr_acct();
            System.out.println("Do you want to deposit or withdraw amount?");
            String d = sc.nextLine();
            if ("deposit".equals(d)) {

                ac.deposit();
            } else if ("withdraw".equals(d)) {

                ac.withdrawl();

                ac.penalty();

            }
        } else {

            System.out.println("please enter the correct account type as per the options provided on the screen");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: So, `Sav_acct` extends `Account`, which has the `withdraw` property.  I'd remove the `public static` from it and it should otherwise be available to `Sav_acct`, the problem is, you're creating new instances of these accounts every time the user makes a choice, so you're getting a new set of properties.

Comment: If I remove public static, then withdraw is not accessible inside the public static void main function for the if(withdraw<2000). How can I resolve this?

Comment: Exactly, `static` is not your friend in this context, you want to use the account's withdraw property instead, but again, as I said, you're creating new instances of the accounts all over the place which means you're not maintaining the states which you're updating

Comment: How can I maintain the state of the variables? Aren't they automatically updated?

Comment: Variables are updated when some code (e.g. your code) assigns a new value to them.  They are not updated automatically.

Comment: Use a single instance of the object - stop creating new instances each time the user does something, state isn't maintained between different instances of a object, each instance will get it's own state

Comment: The `Account` represents a the user's bank account.  In the real world you don't get a new bank account each time you deposit or withdraw money.  So you shouldn't create a new `Account` object each time you do it either.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you so much. Your suggestions helped a lot.

Comment: @MadProgrammer 95% of my code is fixed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `public static` in a variable just to access it . Use `getter` `setter` to access variables of a class. Thats the right way of doing it.

In your case removing`public static` will do fine;
In `Account` class

```
public static double withdraw; 

to 

double withdraw;
```

You are not maintaining any state while creating object for `Account` and  `Sav_acct` class.You are creating two different objects to do 1 job.
You will never get `withdraw` value of `Account` in `Sav_acct` since both are different objects.

You are not maintaining any state while creating objects for the `Account` and  `Sav_acct` classes. You are creating two different objects here.
You will never get the `withdraw` value of `Account` in `Sav_acct` since both are different objects. Plus you are missing the basics of `Inheritence` in OOPS

Since `Sav_acct` is extending the `Account` class it is inheriting all the properties of `Account`, so there is no need of creating an object of the `Account` class.
Instead, create an object of `Sav_acct` and use this obj to perform your operations;

```
Account wi = new Account();
wi.withdrawl();             
Sav_acct in = new Sav_acct();
in.interest();
```

to

```
Sav_acct wi = new Sav_acct();
wi.withdrawl();
wi.interest();
```

You need to know about how Inheritance works in OOPS. [Refer here](https://www.javatpoint.com/inheritance-in-java#:%7E:text=Inheritance%20in%20Java%20is%20a,are%20built%20upon%20existing%20classes.)

### The main problem

You are declaring objects multiple times whenever you needed.Eg:-

```
System.out.println("Enter your account type: Savings Account or Current Account");
String t = sc.nextLine();
if ("Savings Account".equals(t)) {
    System.out.println("Do you want to deposit or withdraw amount?");
    String d = sc.nextLine();
    if ("deposit".equals(d)) {
        Account de = new Account();        // creating Account object  
        de.deposit();
    }
    else if ("withdraw".equals(d)) {
        Account wi = new Account();   // creating Account object  again
        wi.withdrawl();
        Sav_acct in = new Sav_acct();
        in.interest();
    }
}
```

In the above why create `Account de = new Account();` separately for both `deposit` and `withdraw` just declare one object after getting the account type name and use it to perform respective jobs.

```
System.out.println("Enter your account type: Savings Account or Current Account");
String t = sc.nextLine();
if ("Savings Account".equals(t)) {

    Sav_acct acc = new Sav_acct(); //creating sav_acct object here and use 
    
    System.out.println("Do you want to deposit or withdraw amount?");
    String d = sc.nextLine();
    if ("deposit".equals(d)) {
        // Account de = new Account(); no need
        acc.deposit();
    }
    else if ("withdraw".equals(d)) {
        //Account wi = new Account(); no need
        acc.withdrawl();
        //Sav_acct in = new Sav_acct(); no need again
        acc.interest();
    }
}
```

Redesign your code inside main method otherwise, most of the thing is fine

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped a ton. The one last problem that I'm facing is while choosing "Savings Account" when choosing the withdraw option, I'm not getting the interest added. It's again going 0. I've even reduced the object as everyone said and only using one object to do respective tasks. I don't understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: add the updated code in your post. I guess you need to update some value inside `interest` method.

Comment: I am getting this as result`Your new balance with interest is 2300.0` after entering `200` as withdrawal amount.

Comment: yes but it should add the interest as well while withdrawing. How would that be possible? It should add it for the code I wrote. That's why I'm calling interest().

Comment: Can you provide and input and output sample ?

Comment: "I am getting this as result Your new balance with interest is 2300.0 after entering 200 as withdrawal amount". This itself is an input and output sample.